# Flexbox - image disappear with column

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I'm a little bit stuck to be honest. Here is an example of my original code, the problem is that when I change my flex direction from row to column my picture disappears and I don't understand why =>

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

body {
  background-color: rgb(104, 92, 76);
}

.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row-reverse;
  background-color: black;
  max-width: 700px;
  margin: 20vh auto;
}

.content {
  width: 100%;
}

.text {
  color: white;
}

.image {
  background: url('https://www.silocreativo.com/en/wp-content/uploads/2017/04/flexbox-cssgrid-practical-example.png');
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="image"></div>

  <div class="content">
    <div class="text"> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Quia corporis repudiandae Lorem Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Quisquam aut
      autem molestias debitis unde atque quam at assumenda. Atque sint illo rerum magnam aperiam suscipit commodi repudiandae officia! ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Fugiat quidem quasi sint culpa et rem quas deserunt labore laboriosam
      mollitia. Consequatur lorem minus earum sint eius reiciendis, deleniti id vero sapiente. officiis consequuntur voluptas optio dolore nobis blanditiis adipisci maxime itaque ducimus sit incidunt, eveniet doloremque cupiditate debitis deserunt ad!
      elit. Optio nihil officia commodi nostrum iure dignissimos officiis, consectetur, quae minus libero qui hic quis voluptas et quas similique vero neque facere. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Dolores tenetur, veniam nobis
      nulla molestiae recusandae quia a reiciendis corrupti exercitationem delectus iure ducimus ea odio animi cumque et optio eum! </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: It doesn't have anything to give it any height, so it shrinks to 0 pixels ...

Comment: @CBroe What property suggest you to me ? I try to put the height but i dont have any difference

Comment: You need to specify a height in a unit other than percent.

Comment: Done its working. You know why auto or min max doesnt works ? If you have any advices/websites for better understanding im open ! Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Since there is nothing that specifies the height on the `<div class="image"></div>`, it has a height of 0px. You could set the height to a certain value, like x `vh` or `px`,
but I would recommend using the `img` tag instead:

`<img src="https://www.silocreativo.com/en/wp-content/uploads/2017/04/flexbox-cssgrid-practical-example.png"/>` in place of `<div class="image"></div>`.

This way, the width and height are set to the dimensions of the actual image if nothing else is specified.

Comment: Thanks, so if i understand with divs i have to size manually, and with the property image, the sizing is done automatically according to the elements that surround it?

Comment: Not quite, by default divs stretch to the width and height of their contents. So if there is nothing inside the div, it will have a size of 0x0 pixels. An image will use the size of the source image, so if you use a 640x480px image, this will be the size of the img element.

For both of these you can use CSS to override the width and height in many different ways, one of which is the flex layout you were using. The flex layout is why the div has a width: In the column layout, it makes every piece of content have the same width. In a row layout, it makes every piece of content the same height

Comment: This is also why your image was displayed as intended in the row layout: The height of the image was set to the height of your text. If you want to dive into these things a bit more, there are many good sites for that - I can recommend the HTML and CSS tutorials and references on w3schools.com, for example :)

Comment: Thanks for this ! Its more clearer for me right now

Answer (score 0):

Your `image` tag has not an height specified, you need something like this to set the size of the div:

```
.image {
  flex-basis: 200px; // or height: 200px;
}
```

Otherwise you can use the img tag instead of the background, so you can show the image at his correct dimensions. Remember to set `height: auto` to the img tag in this case.

Answer (score 0):

A flex item needs either a height setting or content adding *(which will determine the height)*. As the image div has no content or height its height is set to 0.

I don't recommend setting height on flex items as this is contrary to how flex works. You should set a height on the flex container and use [flex-basis](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_flex.asp) to set the height of your flex items.

This will allow your flex items to be responsive. If you want the image to have a fixed height you should set it's flex property to `flex:0 0 <height>`;

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  background-color: black;
  max-width: 700px;
  margin: 20vh auto;
  height: 400px;
}

.image {
  display: flex;
  background: url('https://www.silocreativo.com/en/wp-content/uploads/2017/04/flexbox-cssgrid-practical-example.png');
  flex: 1;
}

.content {
  flex: 1;
}

.text {
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="image"></div>

  <div class="content">
    <div class="text">Hey la bonbone est remplis de cocaine Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Quia corporis repudiandae Lorem Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Quisquam aut
      autem molestias debitis unde atque quam at assumenda. Atque sint illo rerum magnam aperiam suscipit commodi repudiandae officia! ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Fugiat quidem quasi sint culpa et rem quas deserunt labore laboriosam
      mollitia. Consequatur lorem minus earum sint eius reiciendis, deleniti id vero sapiente. officiis consequuntur voluptas optio dolore nobis blanditiis adipisci maxime itaque ducimus sit incidunt, eveniet doloremque cupiditate debitis deserunt ad!
      elit. Optio nihil officia commodi nostrum iure dignissimos officiis, consectetur, quae minus libero qui hic quis voluptas et quas similique vero neque facere. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Dolores tenetur, veniam nobis
      nulla molestiae recusandae quia a reiciendis corrupti exercitationem delectus iure ducimus ea odio animi cumque et optio eum! </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: Thanks its working but on my original code i have two problems with this, my footer is in the middle of page and the second is my overlay of color inside my div image disappear too